# DynamoDB - Querying Partitions that have Records with different Partitions Key Values

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have been reading the DynamoDB documentation and understand that the partition key determines the physical partition a record will be stored. However, if the partition key has n values, that does not imply there will be n partitions. This is illustrated by the following:

[image]

"Fish" and "Lizard" reside in the same partition despite having different partition key values. So how does DynamoDB deal with queries for "Fish" records? Will it just sort all the records in this partition by the sort key (Name) and perform a binary search? But in that case there can be multiple records with the same Name (Sort key). Is it fair to say the time complexity of a read on a composite key query is always O(log n) where n is the size of the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB first stores items which share the same partition key (Item collection) physically close together and sorted by a sort key.

When you do a look up by partition key it's a constant O(1) to look up the first item because DynamoDB can point straight to that location on the disk (SSD). No other partition key needs to be read during the lookup.